# How to List Drawable Images in Array XML in Android

Tags: java, android, arrays, xml

hello guy i am new with Android and java and i am trying to list drawable images in arry but i can't 
i am using this code for xml

res/vslues/db.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<string-array name="foodname">

    <item>2</item>

</string-array>

<string-array name="foodItem">
    <item>@drawable/aa</item>



</string-array>
```

---

```
 <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/txtSearchResult"
        android:gravity="center"

    />
```

---

im using this java code to show textview in my layout.xml how i can fix it to show pictures insted of text ?

```
 public void food(){

    String item="" ;
    for(int i=0; i< foodname.length;i++){

        item=foodname[i] ;
        if(item.equals(text.getText().toString()))
        {
            tvResult.setText(fooditem[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

321321321321321321 space

```
if(id==R.id.action_search)
    {
        String foodname=text.getText().toString() ;
        String content =tvResult.getText().toString() ;
        Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
        String shareBody = content;
        sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, foodname);
```

Comment: i'm not sure I understood what you ask for. you can use ImageView instead of TextView if you want to show images. Also you have this setBackgroundResource method for every view which sets a background drawable - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundResource(int)

Comment: thanks marin for your answer i want to add img insted of text in result of search  android:id="@+id/txtSearchResult"

Comment: Element is not `<string-array>`, it's just `<array>` http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#TypedArray